# Simple Kibana table refresh data not changing

Tags: elasticsearch, visualization, kibana

I am very new to Elasticsearch and Kibana.  I have setup an index with a number of documents that I want to monitor as a table on the dashboard.

The JSON documents stored in elastic search simply have four fields.

I created/saved a search on the discover tab with all four fields and then added that search to my dashboard.

I then set the auto refresh to every 5 seconds.

- If I update an existing document the table does **NOT** change on the next refresh.
- If I add/remove new documents to elasticsearch they appear/disappear in the table on the next refresh.
- Table flickers every 5s so it is clearly re-rendering.
- Examining the network traffic shows that the response to the query contains the new data.
- Pressing the arrow drop-down next to the row in the table shows the correct data
- Refreshing the entire page shows the new data

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you need to update an existing document? is this the only scenario in which your data is not getting refreshed?

Comment: I just want to have a static list of items.  It isn't a time-based series, it is just a static list of information.  So when the document updates I want to see the update on the dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Kibana 4.4.2 adding a Search to the Dashboard does not seem to update dynamically. This may or may not be by-design or a bug.

But thanks to the elasticsearch forums I did get this [response](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/dashboard-table-doesnt-refresh/45627).

Summary: Creating a table visualization and splitting the rows and adding each individual term as updates when the data changes.